# .htaccess rewrite url with get parameter With PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL that looks like:

```
search.php?tmp=Hello&A=&B[]=12&B[]=14&vars=100
```

OR

```
search.php?tmp=Hello&A=&B[]=1&B[]=14&B[]=4785&vars=100&cat=PC
```

(parameters not stable)
And i would like to be like :

```
search/Hello/&A=&B[]=12&B[]=14&vars=100
search/Hello/&A=&B[]=1&B[]=14&B[]=4785&vars=100&cat=PC
```

I've tried and it works fine

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    # internal forward

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(.+?)/(.+?)\/?$ search.php?tmp=$1&$2 [NC]
   # external rewrite

    #RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} search\.php\?tmp=([^\s]+) [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^ /search/%1? [R=302,L]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search\.php\?tmp=([^\s&]+)&(.*)  [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /search/%1/%2? [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

Problem I want get same parameters WITH GET methode .
But the output of print_r($_REQUEST);

```
Array ( [tmp] => search [hello] => )
```

I want to have an output like

```
Array ( [tmp] => Hello [A] => [B] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 14 [2] => 4785 ) [vars] => 100 )
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

So you want to sort array `$B` in ascending numberical order?

Theres a command for that, no prizes for guessing what it's called. Just run:

```
sort($B);
```